# Series of a product of series

Tags: series-expansion, products

I am writing a code where I have to multiply large series truncated at some order, say 100.
As a result I want again a series up to order 100, and I want to get it in the fastest way.

I have tried a number of approaches and I am wondering wether there is something better:

We start with

`s1 = Series[ f1 , {x,0,100}]
 s2 = Series[ f2 , {x,0,100}]`

and then I tried

1)   `p = s1 s2`

2)   `p = Series[ Normal[s1] Normal[s2] // Expand, {x,0,100}]`

3)   `p =Sum[Sum[s1[[3,l]] s2[[3,k-l]],{l,0,k}] ,{k,0,100}]`

now, although a bit counter-intuitive for me, the second method seem to be the fastest. I don't understand why, since in this way I am computing many more terms than needed (from 200 to 100*100=10000). The third method takes much longer, altough is the minimal amount of computation I have to do, the first is somewhat in the middle.

Any explanation of what is going on? And advices on how to improve?

Comment: what is the definition of `f1` and `f2` ? at least,example is need.

Comment: I think is irrelevant, they are just regular functions expanded at a regular point. If you prefer, just think of having directly s1 and s2 written as (regular) series of the form Sum_{i=0}^100 a_i x^i

Answer (score 2):

I tried the following code:

```
ClearAll[a, b, x, doit];
test[M_] := Module[{s1, s2},
  s1 = Series[Sum[a[n] x^n, {n, 0, M}], {x, 0, M}];
  s2 = Series[Sum[b[n] x^n, {n, 0, M}], {x, 0, M}];
  Print["1: ", Timing[s1*s2][[1]]];
  Print["2: ", Timing[Series[Normal[s1] Normal[s2], {x, 0, M}]][[1]]];
  Print["3: ", Timing[Series[
     Sum[Sum[ a[n - k] b[k], {k, 0, n}] x^n, {n, 0, M}], {x, 0, M}]][[1]]];
  Print["4: ", Timing[Series[
     Sum[ListConvolve[Array[a, n + 1, 0], Array[b, n + 1, 0]][[1]] x^n,
     {n, 0, M}], {x, 0, M}]][[1]]];

];
```

I tried `test[300]` twice. With a fresh kernel, the first time I got these timings:

```
1: 0.796875
2: 0.96875
3: 90.046875
4: 2.390625
```

and the second time I got these timings:

```
1: 0.796875
2: 0.8125
3: 3.328125
4: 2.265625
```

which is approximately consistent **except** for the 3rd method which was a surprise.
Apparently, Mathematica keeps a cache of **some** computations. The first two methods are very similar in timing and the fastest. There are faster methods, using
`Compile`, for example, if you have numeric coefficients. Some sample code that
you can customize is:

```
f = Compile[{{M, _Integer}, {a, _Integer, 1}, {b, _Integer, 1}},
    Table[Sum[a[[k]] b[[n + 1 - k]], {k, n}], {n, M}]];
test2[M_] := Timing[f[M, Range[M], Range[M]^2]][[1]];
```

Comment: Yeah mathematica keeps a cache, I noticed it as well and was very confusing!

Comment: and yes we do have numeric coefficient, so Compile could be very useful. Could you provide more details about it? Anyway I am upvoting your answer already, thanks!